# Is there a set formula for integration like there is for derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I know that the derivative of $f(x)$ must be
$$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
We can use this formula to derive the derivatives of some functions like $\sin(x)$. Is there such a formula for an integral? In other words, is there a set formula for computing:
$$\int f(x) \ dx$$
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a formula for definite integrals: That is: Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then

$$ \int\limits_{[a,b]} f = \lim_{\Delta x_i \to 0} \sum_{ i=0 }^n f( \xi_i) \Delta x_i$$